# Quickly Add New Series (Column) to Existing Graph - Excel 2013

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have an existing graph, let's say with 2 series against the x-axis.

In my data table I've just added a new, 3rd column that I want to map to this existing graph. How do I do it quickly? I tried copying/pasting the data column into the graph, didn't work.

Also tried this: right-click graph -> "Select Data" -> Ctrl+click to add a new column to the selection. But this messed up my graph. After adding to the selection, a dialog box pops up with left/right checkboxes, when I click OK some kind of new graph line is inserted. I don't want to replace anything, just add the new column to the graph.

Comment: Any answer will depend on the data layout. Please post a screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way: Click the chart and study the highlighted areas in the source data. Click and drag the corner of the blue area to include the new data.

[image]

Another way: In the chart source dialog, change the chart data range to include the desired data.

[image]

A third way: In the chart source dialog, click the "Add" button and specify the location of the new series.

A fourth way: select the data in the spreadsheet, for exampl D1 to D6 and copy. Click the chart and paste. Use Paste Special for fine tuning.

[image]